# Align View to baseline of another TextView

Tags: android

I try to create a simple line that align at bottom after TextView. I use RelativeLayout as a container with alignBaseLine. But the result is not what I need ( See Image Below) Unlike align two TextView, When I align TextView and View it's not align from bottom to top. It's start from top of View to bottom. Is there any way I can achieve this ?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Brand We Love"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `android:layout_alignBaseline` will position a `View` just below the baseline, you can use this constraint to place an invisible `View` there which will act as a guideline and then position your `View` above the guideline:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Brand We Love"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="18sp" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:background="#00000000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For `ConstraintLayout` set the baseline to the bottom and unite baselines.

In short - just add these lines to your `View`:

```
android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/textView"
```